Getting the data pointed to back in the template example where i store the address of the data
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T> class Address
{
    private:
        T* ptr;
        size_t size;
    public:
        Address(T item) : ptr(&item), size(sizeof(item)) {}
        T getItem() const 
        {
            return *ptr;
        }
        long getAddress() const
        {
            return (long int ) ptr;
        }
        long getSize() const
        {
            return size;
        }        
};

template <typename T> 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Address<T> item)
{
    out << "\nItem: " << item.getItem() << "\n";
    out << "Address : " << item.getAddress() << "\n";
    out << "Size : " << item.getSize() << "\n";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Address<char>> ptr_addressObj(new Address('P'));
    std::cout<< *ptr_addressObj << "\n";
}

Produces
Item: 
Address : 140720983114340
Size : 1

How do I get the Item back? Right now it is blank. Same with Address<int>.

The T item in Address constructor ceases to exist at } that finishes constructor, leaving you with a dangling pointer in ptr.

Change constructor to Address(T& item).  Note that there is a burden on the programmer that the item passed to the constructor has to live at least as long as the Address object.

C++ does not give a guarantee that just because you have a pointer, you can get back the item that it once pointed to. In other words forming a pointer does not in any way extend the lifetime of the object being pointed at. It's your responsibility to make sure that when you dereference a pointer that the object pointed to still exists. Your code fails to do that and so you have undefined behaviour.

On a side note, depending on platform and build settings, long may not be large enough to hold a memory address. You should use (u)intptr_t instead.  Or, simply return T* as-is (or void*) since operator<< can print the value of a pointer.
